# Rotativa http error 400 request too long

Tags: c#, cookies, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I'm trying to generate pdf,but after 24-th page header and footer display http error 400 request too.I used each solution from git,manipulate with [ASPXAUTH] but it generate Login page on second pdf.I know that it is problem of cookie duplication so
is it possible to read header content --header-html{0} from cookie someway without using action for it generate or include image to --header-left?